# arduino mega adk + processing

Tags: arduino, processing, adk

I have to send some data from arduino to android. I checked the internet and found the arduino mega adk + processing the most easy way to do it. So i bought the adk board but not even a single ArduinoADKUsb example worked in processing. I have Processing 2.2.1 and Arduino 1.5.6r2. I am getting the processing code compiled but with the following error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread

Process: processing.android.test.adk_analogread, PID: 28362

java.lang.RuntimeException: stub

    at com.android.future.usb.UsbManager.getInstance(Unknown Source)

    at cc.arduino.ADKCommunication.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at cc.arduino.ArduinoAdkUsb.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at processing.android.test.adk_analogread.adk_analogRead.setup(adk_analogRead.java:31)

    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)

    at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)

    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am getting the sketch on my Android phone as well but when I open it says "Unfortunately adk_analogRead has stopped"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading to Processing 2.0.3.  It worked for me for a similar issue.  Google search for Processing and Google Code for the download.

Also, I use a cheap Bluetooth module to send data between Android and Arduino using the Ketai library.

Comment: Hello and thanks for advice. I even tried processing 2.03 but it did not worked. Which version of arduino IDE did you use with processing 2.03?                                                                                         I tried the sweetbt library which is only sending the Analog pins data through bluesmirf silver. Can the ketai library send the multiplexed values from 3 Analog pins? Like for A0 pin I have 8 values to send and similarly for A1 and A2.

Comment: The Ketai library for Android provides communication through osc5 if I recall correctly.  It works flawlessly.  Also, I am using Arduino 1.0.5 and the SoftwareSerial library for the bluetooth connection for a 34K baud serial connection.  That's more than quick enough to pull in 8 x 3 values from the Arduino and send to Android.  The bluesmirf silver is a really good module, but I would read the manual and see if you have to set it up in slave mode.  You can do this by accessing it's AT commands through serial.  That should be enough for you to try now.

Comment: The default mode for bluesmirf silver is the slave mode and yes it can be accessed through AT commands. But I think that wont I have to configure it in the master mode to send values from arduino to android?

Comment: The bluetooth module is a slave in reference to the Arduino.  When you establish a connection between the bluetooth module and the Android, communication can be bi-directional.

Comment: Also, make sure you have Android SDK API 10 and the Google USB driver under extras selected, as required by [Processing for Android](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android).